# RavenDB: inserting record-new line char has disappeared

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ravendb

I want to insert document to the ravenDb. It has property named "Description:
I've written in description-field something like this:

```
1)first row
2 second row
```

and string Description looks like:

```
 "1)first row\r\n2 second row"
```

For sure that string with that value is inputing to the ravenDB
But document in raven db looks like:

```
"1)first row 2 second row"
```

so when it is displayed looks like:

```
"1)first row 2 second row"
```

so it looks ugly.
How can i deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kamil, RavenDBs management UI is not intended to be used by end users. Instead, it is a tool that helps you while developing an application on top of raven. That's why there is no need for the editor to display special characters, because you generally want to view the whole json document there.

However, don't worry - your \r\n characters are preserved when you load the document back into an instanve of a class.

Comment: Thanks for help,but problem is,they aren't. When i load document back and display it-these characters are gone. Look at the end of my question. To be clear: UI: \r\n exist ---> (inserting)-->ravenDb:they gone-->(loading document back)-->UI:they're still gone.

Comment: Kamil, there must be something else in your application that causes this characters to get lost. Raven definitely leaves the string as it is. If you still experience this issues, please drop me an email an we can investigate further.